# Haskell list repeated elements

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to do a function that tells me that, if in list of tuples, if the first element of the tuple is the same in another tuple, the other elements of the tuple must be equal too, and if not, it returns `False`.

```
main> istup [(1,2,3,4,5),(1,2,3,4,5),(1,4,5,6,2),(4,2,1,5,6)]
>>> False
main> istup [(1,2,3,4,5),(1,2,3,4,5),(4,2,1,5,6),(4,2,1,5,6)]
>>> True
```

This is what I have:

```
type Tuple = (a,b,c,d,e)

istup :: [Tuple] -> Bool
istup x = length (nub x) == length x
```

Comment: If there's a single tuple with a given head, does it count as True?

Comment: do you mean you want to check if `head list` is an element of `tail list`?

Answer (score 2):

Just write your description down as Haskell code. These are your conditions:

- for every pair of elements, you want to check some condition
- you define the condition
- you write down what „all pairs“ means:

And this is the resulting code:

```
istup :: [(Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)] -> Bool
istup x = all ok (allPairs x)

ok t1 t2 = if fst5 t1 == fst5 t2 then t1 == t2 else True
    where fst5 (a,_,_,_,_) = a

allPairs x = [(a,b) | a <- x , b <- x]
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's split the task into subtasks.

1) We need to split the list into lists of tuples with the same head, it can be done using Data.List.groupBy, which takes a function to determine whether to put two items in the same sublist:

```
 import Data.List
 import Data.Function (on)
 splitByHead = groupBy ((==) `on` fst5)    -- the function is same as (\a b -> fst5 a == fst5 b)
    where fst5 (a,_,_,_,_) = a
```

2) then we need to check if all items in a sublist are equal (it can be done looking at the length of a list of different items, which is obtained by `nub`):

```
 allEqual = (1 == ) . length . nub
```

3) putting that together:

```
 import Data.List
 import Data.Function (on)

 istup = all ((1 == ) . length . nub) . groupBy ((==) `on` (\(a,_,_,_,_) -> a))
```